# Does 단비 (sweet rain) have Hanja?

Tags: hanja

*Hanja (Korean Hanzi) Dic* gives some possible Hanja for 단비:

> 單婢 團匪 單比 斷碑 斷臂 短臂

None of these seem to match the meaning "sweet rain."

Does 단비 (sweet rain) have Hanja?

Comment: 비 for rain is a native Korean word; the hanja-eo equivalent would be 우 (雨).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. Both morphemes are of non-Sinitic origin [as given by Naver dic](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/acbc4b5d12794ae285059684c4032039), made up of

- (달 + ㄴ) > 단 (*sweet*; see Etymology #7 of [달다](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%8B%AC%EB%8B%A4#Etymology_7))
- [비](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%B9%84) (*rain*)

These are their modern representations of course, for the etymology of 달다 see the [Naver dic entry](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/75c6cb64a580405fafefcf54ca353c76&directAnchor=s89961p454627) with the 아래아 (ㆍ)

Answer (score 2):

This is just to agree with drooze's answer really, but my understanding is also that 단비, unlike many Korean names, is a 'pure' Korean name, not linked to the meaning of Chinese characters.

(Source - I have a friend called 단비, and this was her opinion!)

Answer (score 0):

시우지화時雨之化 : 맹자孟子에 나오는 말로, 때맞춰 내리는 단비가 만물을 살린다는 의미

시우지화 is in 맹자 book and it means that rain of good timing inspires vivid energies to all things. 시우 can be a corresponded to hanja of 단비.